# Stopping a child function when a condition is met ( Without killing the parent function) in R

Tags: r, function, loops

So lets say I have two functions where the Child is counting `1:5` and printing `i`every time . After each print it checks if `i>2`, if it is- it stops. Then there is a parent function which counts  `10:11` , prints `k` and then runs the Child function like so:

```
#Child function:

Child <- function(){
  for (i in 1:5){
   print(i)
   if (i>2){
    stop()
   }
  }
}

#Parent function
for (k in 10:11){
 print(k)
 Child()
}
```

Right now if I run this, when the Child inevitably stops when i=3, the Parent will also stop. I need to find a way to only stop the child Function, and let the parent continue running. So that instead of this:

```
[1] 10
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
Error in Child() :
```

I can get something like this:

```
[1] 10
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
[1] 11
[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 3
```

If there are error messages after each stop is triggered i wouldn't mind that.

Comment: does it need to be a 'stop()' call? Have you looked into the 'tryCatch()' examples? This question smells like homework ;-)

Comment: Change `stop()` to `break()`

Comment: Its not homework, I have simplified the question  since i can not dump 300 libraries here and show you the exact point where my issue is.

Comment: Thank you very much @GKi, that did it... I can tick you if you post as an answer

Comment: `stop()` ends a whole program. `break()` ends the current function/loop. `return()` ends the function as successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest fix is to use `try`:

```
Child <- function(){
  try(
  for (i in 1:5){
    print(i)
    if (i>2){
      stop()
    }
  }, silent = TRUE 
  )
}

#Parent function
for (k in 10:11){
  print(k)
  Child()
}
```